# filter(!is.na(column)) is not removing NA's from column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I'm redoing a study assignment to see if I can improve it and get back into it. The assignment is to write a function that, given 2 variables "state" and "outcome" returns the name of the hospital in the state that has the lowest deathrate for the given outcome/disease.
For some reason my line with filter(!is.na()) does not seem to work. I have a feeling it has to do with the fact that I use paste to select the column name, but In my stests this doesn't seem to matter.

Here is the code:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")

dataSelected <- data %>%
        select("Hospital.Name", "State", "Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack", "Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure", "Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Pneumonia")

colnames(dataSelected) <- c("HostpitalName","State","DeathRateHeartAttack","DeathRateHeartFailure","DeathRatePneumonia")

dataSelected[,3] <- as.numeric(dataSelected[,3])
dataSelected[,4] <- as.numeric(dataSelected[,4])
dataSelected[,5] <- as.numeric(dataSelected[,5])


best <- function(state,outcome){
        column <- paste('DeathRate',outcome, sep = "")
        if (state %in% dataSelected$State < 1){
                return('Invalid state')
        } else if (column %in% colnames(dataSelected) < 1){
                return('Invalid outcome')
        } else{
        BestHospitals <- dataSelected %>%
                select(HostpitalName,State,column) %>%
                filter(!is.na(column)) %>%
                filter(State == state) %>%
                arrange(column,HostpitalName)
        return(BestHospitals[1,1])
        }
}
```

My function call

```
best("AL","HeartAttack")
```

**Version info**

platform       x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
arch           x86_64
os             darwin15.6.0
system         x86_64, darwin15.6.0
status
major          3
minor          6.1
year           2019
month          07
day            05
svn rev        76782
language       R
version.string R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
nickname       Action of the Toes

output of dput(head(dataSelected)):

```
structure(list(HostpitalName = c("SOUTHEAST ALABAMA MEDICAL CENTER", 
"MARSHALL MEDICAL CENTER SOUTH", "ELIZA COFFEE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", 
"MIZELL MEMORIAL HOSPITAL", "CRENSHAW COMMUNITY HOSPITAL", "MARSHALL MEDICAL CENTER NORTH"
), State = c("AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL", "AL"), DeathRateHeartAttack = c(14.3, 
18.5, 18.1, NA, NA, NA), DeathRateHeartFailure = c(11.4, 15.2, 
11.3, 13.6, 13.8, 12.5), DeathRatePneumonia = c(10.9, 13.9, 13.4, 
14.9, 15.8, 8.7)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  We really need to see (some of) your data.  Please add the output from `dput(dataSelected)` (or `dput(head(dataSelected))` to your question, along with your actual call to your `best` function.  Two suggestions: are you sure your data contains `NA` rather than the character `"NA"`?  You cannot pass column names as strings to `dplyr` verbs.  You need to be aware of *non-standard evaluation* or [NSE](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! I've added your suggestions. As can be seen: The data does contain actual NA's. I am actually fairly sure that your second suggestion (passing strings as column names) is the problem. However, how do I elegantly solve the problem of converting the "outcome" argument into a column name so I can use it with dplyr?

Answer (score 0):

How about filtering by the column number instead of name?

```
best <- function(state,outcome){
        column <- paste('DeathRate',outcome, sep = "")
        if (state %in% dataSelected$State < 1){
                return('Invalid state')
        } else if (column %in% colnames(dataSelected) < 1){
                return('Invalid outcome')
        } else{
        BestHospitals <- dataSelected %>%
                select(HostpitalName,State,column) %>%
                filter(!is.na(.[,3])) %>%
                filter(State == state) %>%
                arrange(desc(.[3])))
        return(BestHospitals[1,1])
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Wouldn't this result in the same problem for select though?

Comment: No it won't! Thank you for this elegant answer.

For documentation: I removed one of the parenthesis on the "arrange" line and removed desc because it would return the highest deathrate instead of the lowest.

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty to rewrite your function a bit.

```
# it is usually a bad idea to insert a global variable (like your data frame) inside a function. 
best <- function(dat=NULL,state=NULL,outcome=NULL){ 
  
  column <- paste('DeathRate',outcome, sep = "")
  
  if (!state %in% dat$State | !column %in% colnames(dat)){
    stop('Invalid input')
  } # negating and using or "|" makes it easier to read
  else{
    BestHospitals <- dat %>%
      select(HostpitalName,State,column) %>%
      na.omit() %>% # for your purpose the much more concise na.omit() is a better option
      filter(State == state) %>%
      arrange(column,HostpitalName) %>% 
      filter(row_number()==1) #dplyr way to choose the first row
    
    return(BestHospitals)
  }
}

best(dat = dataSelected, state = "AL", outcome = "HeartAttack")

                   HostpitalName State DeathRateHeartAttack
1 ELIZA COFFEE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL    AL                 18.1
```

Comment: Thanks :) this helps me learn

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tidyverse-like version of your function.

As D.J. comments, it's not good practice to include a reference to a global object (`dataSelected`) inside your function.  Far better to pass this as a parameter.  This also has the beneficial side effect of allowing you to use the function in a pipe.

Also, `HostpitalName` might be a typo.  Did you perhaps mean `HospitalName`?  As you've used the strange spelling more than once, I've retained it.

Whilst I understand why you've allowed the user to shorten the name of the required outcome by pasting the common prefix of `"DeathRate"` to the valuepassed in `outcome`, this probably isn't best practice, as requires the user to *know* this convention, and limits the use of the function to data frames and columns that follow this convention.  It also doesn't fit well with tidyverse syntax.

```
best <- function(d, state, outcome){
  # By adding d as the first parameter, you make it easy to use the function in
  # a pipe.  And on data frames other than dataSelected.
  qOutcome <- enquo(outcome)
  # calling stop is better than returning an error message as 
  # it stops processing immediately.
  if (!(state %in% (d %>% distinct(State) %>% pull(State) ))) {
    stop('Invalid state')
  }
  if (!(as_label(qOutcome) %in% colnames(d)) ){
    stop('Invalid outcome')
  }
  # Converting original code to equivalent tidyverse idioms.
  # HostpitalName should perhaps be HospitalName in the source data frame
  d %>%
    select(HostpitalName, State, !! qOutcome) %>%
    filter(!is.na(!! qOutcome)) %>%
    filter(State == state) %>%
    arrange(!! qOutcome, HostpitalName) %>% 
    pull(HostpitalName) %>% 
    head(1)
}
```

So we can then write

```
dataSelected %>% best("AL", DeathRateHeartFailure)
[1] "ELIZA COFFEE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL"
```

or, say,

```
dataSelected %>% best("AL", DeathRatePneumonia)
[1] "MARSHALL MEDICAL CENTER NORTH"
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is all very interesting. The spelling is weird indeed, unfortunately a typo made by someone who created the original data set.